# Скрипты для bledshapes

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня проблема в unity.Нужно сделать так чтобы в unity при нажатии кнопки менялся blendshapes(параметры лица). Есть модель человека в Unity и нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки срабатывал blendshapes у меня я это Open.Что я делаю не так?Почему он не обращается к bkendshapes?Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает.

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class NewBehaviourScript4 : MonoBehaviour {
 
SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer;
Mesh skinnedMesh;
int Open = 500;
int blendSpeed = 100;
bool eyesClosed = false;
 
 
public void Start()
    {
skinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
 
skinnedMesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer> ().sharedMesh;
    }
 
 
public void Update ()
    {
 
    //(float Open = 0f; Open < 100f; Open++)
        if (Open !=0 )
{
            skinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight (100,Open);
            
//skinnedMeshRenderer.updateWhenOffscreen = true;
            //Debug.Log ("BlendShape value" + skinnedMeshRenderer.GetBlendShapeWeight (100));
 
            }
    }
 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh я не уверен но это возможно то что надо

[оригинал](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh.html)